# running java code from oracle

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

I am using oracle as following version:

> Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>
> PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
>
> "CORE 12.1.0.2.0  Production"
>
> TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production NLSRTL Version
>   12.1.0.2.0 - Production

**Version of java:**

```
SELECT dbms_java.get_ojvm_property(PROPSTRING=>'java.version') FROM dual
```

returns

> 1.6.0_81

I also create a class within Java Ecplise (NERO) - version 1.8.0.0 jre.

```
public class TestWEBClass {
    public static String getWEBString() {
        String s = "abcde";
        // s = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") ;
        return s;
    }
}
```

I added a folder in oracle:

```
create or replace directory MYFOLDER_WORKDIR as 'C:\myfolder\projects\java';
```

I compile that class, put in on the above folder, and by sqldeveloper tool add that class (right click on JAVA subfolder -> load java -> oracle directory class -> choose MYFOLDER_WORKDIR and the class file.

After above:

```
create or replace FUNCTION TEST_TESTCLSS RETURN varchar AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
name 'TestWEBClass.getWEBString() return varchar'
```

when running in sql:

```
select TEST_TESTCLSS from dual;
```

The following exception encountered:

> ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError : TestWEBClass (Unsupported major.minor version 52.0)
>   29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
>   *Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
>              resolved by the Java code.
>   *Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.

So I have thought of using 32bit JRE system library - (in eclipse: package -> right mouse click -> properties -> libraries -> add exterenal library -> choose folder of the library -> installed library -> add -> standard vm -> choose the right folder). Same error.

So, I decided to copy the folder from oracle-java to my own computer.
Now I get in my code when compiling in eclipse the error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TestWEBClass : Unsupported major.minor 
>   version 52.0  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) Exception in
>   thread "main"

How can I proceed in order run a simple java code (using class) from oracle?

Can I just put new version of Java JDK in Oracle side? What is the best practice doing that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to compile this simple class from source within Oracle - do you have to compile it externally (in which case you'd have to use a 1.6 JDK in Eclipse) and load it?

Comment: I did refer to the same jdk of oracle (put it on folder, I have tried another version of 32bit, put on code some check that I am doing right:s = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") ;, and for 32bit it was fine, so I knew how to attach to other java version, so I copy one by one from oracle the jdk folder from E:\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\OPatch\jre\lib ).

What I think is version of jdk differ of version of jre, but it is not obvious how to do that.

But I think I solved the problem, by choosing the execution environment after check the checkbox for javase-1.6 on that dialogbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be solved for attaching same version of jre to the jdk files.

That can be done, by choosing the execution environment (project -> properties -> libraries -> choose the relevant library -> edit -> and checking the checkbox for javase-1.6 on that dialogbox).